# How to query mongodb with search criteria in dict and array objects

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to query the sub-document based on the search criteria as follows.

document:

```
{
    '_id' : 1,
    'latest' :  {
        'name' : 'tango',
        'version' : 3,
        ...
    },
    'prev' : [
        {
          'name' : 'alpha',
          'version' : 1,
          ...
        },
        {
          'name' : 'charlie',
          'version' : 2,
          ...
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to search document where `_id` and `latest.version` or `prev[x].version` matches given inputs.

The version can either be found in the latest or previous documents, and the same version is not present in both.

`_id` -> 1
`version` -> 3

result:

```
{
    'name' : 'tango',
    'version' : 3,
    ...
}
```

`_id` -> 1
`version` -> 1

result:

```
{
    'name' : 'alpha',
    'version' : 1,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `$match` condition for `latest` object and `prev` array `version` field
- `$cond` condition to check if `latest.version` is match then return `latest` object else filter `prev` array and match `version`,
- `$arrayElemAt` to get first element from filter result
- `$replaceRoot` to replace above result to root

```
var _id = 1;
var version = 1;
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        { _id: _id },
        {
          $or: [
            { "latest.version": version }, //input here
            { "prev.version": version } //input here
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $cond: [
          { $eq: ["$latest.version", version] }, //input here
          "$latest",
          {
            $arrayElemAt: [
              {
                $filter: {
                  input: "$prev",
                  cond: { $eq: ["$$this.version", version] } //input here
                }
              },
              0
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/mslU84U-53q)

Comment: Thank you @turivishal for your help. I worked like a charm.

Comment: I am sorry, bit new to this. I just accepted the answer.